# Sources of information on algorithms for finding Hamiltonian cycles (Pósa)

Tags: co.combinatorics, random-graphs, hamiltonian-graphs, hamiltonian-paths, network-theory

I research various algorithms in complex networks and I am quite new in this field. I am currently focusing on random geometric graphs -  Pósa's algorithm for finding a hamiltonian cycle. Can you offer me information sources (articles, books, websites, etc.) to research the subject?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

See [A Brief Introduction to Hamilton Cycles in Random Graphs](http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~gbrunet/project2.pdf) for an introductory overview, and [arXiv:1901.07139](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.07139) for an annotated biography.